# Visit Request.Url when use ajax in MVC

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

When I visit the `Request.Url` when use ajax in MVC, the url will add some tag like:

> www.test.com/home/index/4?X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest

how to get the actual url or how to remove the tag without any hard coding?

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
string url = Request.Url.AbsolutePath; // should give you /home/index/4
```

and if you wanted an absolute url you could try that:

```
var builder = new UriBuilder(Request.Url);
builder.Query = string.Empty;
string url = builder.ToString(); // should give you http://www.test.com/home/index/4
```